# EC2 instance access port 3030

Tags: linux, tcp, amazon-ec2, fuseki

Yesterday when I left work, everything worked fine, I turned off my AWS EC2 instance.

This morning, I turn on the instance and it turns on automatically a Fuseki server on this instance. I can see it running using `ps -aux | grep "Fuseki"`.

This server is accessible through port 3030 which I opened in AWS ==> security group ==> Inbound ==> TCP 3030 ==> 0.0.0.0/0 (which should be everyone).

I can access this server from the instance with firefox in http://localhost:3030.
My problem is that since this morning, I am no more able to access it through an other computer by entering http://myAwsIp:3030, it times out.

To resolve this, I tried in localhost from AWS, it worked. I checked my ports on AWS as I said before, they are opened. I runned `netstat -lntu` in the instance and it bringed me `tcp :::3030 LISTEN`. I tried to nmap -p 3030 IP from my Windows computer and it bringed me `Host is up` and `3030/tcp filtered arepa-cas`.

So everything seems to be ok for me, except that I can't connect from another computer. I don't know where to look anymore, any hint ?

Comment: Did you check that your instance doesn't have a different external IP?

Comment: I think yes, I am trying to reach it using the IP address I find under "PublicIP" in the "Instance" panel of the EC2 Management console.

Comment: I resolved my problem. It appears that the Wifi I used was down and it automatically switched me to a public wifi, that wifi was what prevented me from accessing the server.
What I don't understand, however, is that if I was unable to access this server from this Wifi connection, it means that people that will try to use my website may be expecting the same problem... how can I fix that ?

Comment: It is not unusual that public/free wifi allows only connections to port 80